# Counting total and true condition lines

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

How to count the number of lines in a table and the number of lines where a certain condition is true without resorting to subselects like this:

```
create table t (a integer);
insert into t (a) values (1), (2), (null);

select
    (select count(*) from t) as total_lines,
    (select count(*) from t where a = 1) as condition_true
;
 total_lines | condition_true 
-------------+----------------
           3 |              1
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
select count(*) as total_lines, count(a = 1 or null) as condition_true
from t
;
 total_lines | condition_true 
-------------+----------------
           3 |              1
```

It works because:

First while `count(*)` counts all lines regardless of anything, `count(my_column)` will count only those lines where my_column is not null:

```
select count(a) as total
from t
;
 total 
-------
     2
```

Second `(false or null)` returns `null` so whenever my condition is not met it will return `null` and will not be counted by `count(condition or null)` which only counts not nulls.

Comment: It's great that you decided to share your experience with others. The thing is, this question has been asked (and answered) on SO many times. Try searching for "sql conditional count" and you'll be able to see for yourself.

Comment: @AndriyM Point to one post with this same solution. And another with the same question.

Comment: Ah, so I find you what you ask and you withdraw your question ? And from now on everyone should be coming to me to ask to search for *their* questions before posting them? Thank you very much! :) I offered you a search term to try. When I tried it, it gave me lots of questions. The fundamental question was the same in many cases, and it was same as yours I reckon. Anyway, I was merely suggesting an explanation for someone's downvote, that's all. And I still think it was nice of you to decide to share what you'd learnt.

Comment: Just had to +1 this solution because it also perfectly solves my use case where i'm left-joining to a table (users) to count several things, including a boolean condition (did the user log in recently?). When the left-join produces no left-table results, this solution succeeds by returning `0` where the `SUM` solution results in `NULL`.

Answer (score 3):

Use `SUM(condition)`!

```
select
    count(*) as total_lines,
    sum(a = 1) as condition_true
from t
```

See it working [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ddfce/3).

This works because in mysql, `true` is `1` and `false` is `0`, so the `sum()` of a condition will add `1` when it's true and `0` when it's false - which effectively counts the number of times the condition is true.

Many people falsely believe you need a `case` statement, but you don't with mysql (you do with some other databases)

Comment: The question is for both MySQL and PostgreSQL, so -1 on this non-portable answer. In any database where `TRUE` is a actual boolean (rather than a numeric value), this is unlikely to work.

Answer (score 3):

this can be easily done using a condition inside count. I don't know if its the optimized method of doing it but it gets the work done

you can do it as follows

```
select count(*) as total_lines, COUNT(CASE WHEN a = 1 THEN 1 END) as condition_true from t
```

you can check it here

[sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ddfce/8)